# What is the difference between direct product and direct sum of a finite number of group representations.

Tags: vector-spaces, representation-theory

I have been reading in Fulton & Harris's book on representation theory and it talks about things like the decomposition of a direct product of representations $ V \otimes V $ into a direct sum of representations. It seems to me there is a real difference between a finite direct sum of representations and a direct product even though they agree on vector spaces. Is this difference real and if so , what is it?

Comment: Can you tell on what page it talks about direct product ?

Comment: Check for example page 10 and 11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\otimes$ denotes the [**tensor** product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), not the direct product. This is different even for vector spaces; the tensor product of vector spaces of dimensions $m, n$ has dimension $mn$ rather than $m+n$ for the direct product or direct sum.

Comment: aah thanks a lot, that solves it.

Comment: I'd like to add a link to a lucid presentation aiming to clear up the different notions of *direct sum*, *direct product* and the *tensor direct product* [http://suchideas.com/articles/maths/math-phys/tensor-direct-products-vs-direct-sums/](http://suchideas.com/articles/maths/math-phys/tensor-direct-products-vs-direct-sums/)